# Refreshing asp.net identity claims when used for ui

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

As far as I've understood, I'm now supposed to use claims to store any user data. I'm having trouble updating the claims.

Let's say I have two claims:

```
UserID
UserName
```

In my main menu i present the username, via e g

```
<div>
@Model.UserName
</div>
```

The site is online and users log in.

A while later I want to update the site, so I add a Claim, and have:

```
UserID
UserName
UserAge
```

I want my main menu to be updated accordingly and use

```
<div>
@Model.UserName (@Model.UserAge years old)
</div>
```

Now, since my already logged in users don't have to relogin, UserAge doesn't even exist, and I'd get a NullException. How is such a scenario supposed to be handled?

Comment: I guessing you will need to remove their cookie next time they access the site and force them to relogin (In GenerateUserIdentityAsync)? Not sure - I'm investigating something similar.